# Cordova android Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android, cordova

Using Cordova 8.1.2 and android platform 7.1.4. When running in debug mode all image files are not found.

`<img src="static/icons/avatar_opera.png">`

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND avatar_opera.png:1`

When I manually add image full path 'file:android_asset/www/'

`<img src="file:android_asset/www/static/icons/avatar_opera.png">`

image is found. That is very strange behaviour. Do I really need to change all images path to full path 'file:android_asset/www/' when I am building for android platform?

Comment: You don't have to add the full path, in my app I reference it with `img/whatever.png` where `img` folder is in the same folder as my `index.html`. You need to make sure you're running `cordova prepare` to copy all your files into the platforms. You also need to make sure you're not building directly inside the platforms folder.

Comment: @jm-agms ```cordova prepare``` didn't help

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution? I have the same problem :) If I manually add 'file:android_asset/www/' image will appear. But this is not a solution I guess.